# Datastax DSC 2.1 not providing +2.1.15?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

looking at http://download.datastax.com/community it seem like they stopped patching 2.1 since 2.1.15, anywhere to verify if they stopped providing newer patches to their 2.1 branch?

Suggestion maybe where to find other rpm/yum repo for cassandra 2.1 in case?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

It's browsable here:

http://rpm.datastax.com/community/noarch/

2.1.15 seems do be a valid download:

http://rpm.datastax.com/community/noarch/cassandra21-2.1.15-1.noarch.rpm

there are no versions after that, I would say it's as good as it gets with 2.1

Comment: I would like 2.1.16 as I'm told this: "Actually If you’re not on 2.1.16, then you are probably hitting CASSANDRA-12112 – it’s not counting partition deletions in the histogram"